# How to retrieve all texts, including 'non-between' html tags using cheerio on node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

Please consider the following HTML content:

```
I like <div>turtles, </div><b> cookies</b> and brownies.
```

I am using below code to retrieve contents:

```
 txt=$.root().find('*').contents().filter(function() {
            if (this.type === 'text'){
              varArr.push(this.data);
              return this.data
            } 
    }).text();
```

txt is: turtles, cookies

If I add  tags

```
<html>I like <div>turtles, </div><b> cookies</b> and brownies</html>
```

I get:
I like and brownies. turtles, cookies

I want: 
I like turtles, cookies and brownies.

It is not picking initial and last texts, which is not between tags. Is there a way to retrieve all text - outside and nested on html tags?)

Comment: What about `$("html").text()`?

Comment: That would work to extract only texts, but I have to interact with each piece of text found, ie using map or filter functions. Just edited my question providing a better example.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up transforming original string in order to retrieve required values. I am checking if string starts or ends with html tag. If not, I added a tmp tag.
ie:

```
<tmp>I like </tmp><div>turtles, </div><b> cookies</b> and </tmp>brownies</tmp>
```

After this, I removed tmp tags.